# nant replace regex in file while preserving encoding

Tags: nant

I'm using a Nant build to update the dates in C# AssemblyInfo.cs files (lots of them).
Each file contains a line like...

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright Whoever 2020-2021")]
```

or

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright Whoever 2021")]
```

and I'm updating that to say

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright Whoever 2020-2022")]
```

or

```
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright Whoever 2021-2022")]
```

I have a property `versionFilePath` which contains the name of the file, and I'm doing...

```
  <loadfile file="${versionFilePath}" property="versionFileContent"/>
  <regex pattern="^(?'prefix'\[assembly:\s+AssemblyCopyright\(&quot;.+?)(?'fromdate'\d\d\d\d)(?'todate'\-\d\d\d\d)?(?'suffix'.*&quot;\)\])" input="${versionFileContent}" options="Multiline" />

  <loadfile file="${versionFilePath}" property="versionFileContent">
    <filterchain>
      <replacestring from="${prefix}${fromdate}${todate}${suffix}" to="${prefix}${fromdate}-${datetime::get-year(datetime::now())}${suffix}" />
    </filterchain>
  </loadfile>
  <echo file="${versionFilePath}">${versionFileContent}</echo>
```

And this is *basically* working, however the file that it is writing is a different encoding than the one which it loaded; and the version control system we're using doesn't like that very much.

How can I make it do the replacement without altering the encoding? Can I capture the encoding when the file is being loaded so that I can use the same value when the file is being written? Or is there a better way of doing this, where I can just do the Regex replace directly on the file?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a solution which keeps the original encoding, but you might force the echo task to a defined encoding (one that is accepted by your VCS) since
[`echo`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/echo.html) has an `encoding` attribute (as least as of version 0.92).

```
  <echo file="${versionFilePath}" encoding="iso-8859-1">${versionFileContent}</echo>
```

**Update:** To make it a bit clearer: There's no good way of telling from a source text file what its encoding is. You can make a good guess (take a look at Python module [chardet](https://pypi.org/project/chardet/)), but most of the time everything depends on meta-information. My advice is:

- Get your source `CommonAssemblyInfo.cs` to a shared encoding e.g., [UTF-8](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3629) with [BOMs](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).
- This is highly experimental: You could use the same `encoding` attribute for [`loadfile`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/loadfile.html) and [`echo`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/echo.html) task. If you [take a look at the NAnt sources](https://github.com/nant/nant/blob/master/src/NAnt.Core/Tasks/LoadFileTask.cs) [`loadfile`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/loadfile.html) encoding attribute defaults to [Encoding.Default](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=netframework-4.5.2) (which is pretty straightforward and according to the doc means `Unless an encoding is specified, the encoding associated with the system's current ANSI code page is used`). [According to the NAnt sources](https://github.com/nant/nant/blob/master/src/NAnt.Core/Tasks/EchoTask.cs) the [`echo`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/echo.html) task defaults to [UTF-8](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3629). If you choose [ASCII](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.ascii?view=netframework-4.5.2) encoding for both, you might be safe for most of [8-Bit-encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859) since you're replacing characters with ANSI code < 128 only.

Comment: Thanks. The only piece of the puzzle left is how to get the encoding from `loadfile` (or some other way), to pass into that `encoding` attribute of `echo`.

Comment: OK. I refined my answer a bit

Comment: Upvote for being helpful; but this answer basically proposes to set all of the files to a particular encoding, and as explained in the question, if I do that, it causes the issue to the VCS for the ones which were different. Given that "tweaking files" is a common thing that builds need to do, it seems an odd oversight that there isn't a way of doing this. In the absence of other answers, I guess I'll just write my own task to do a regex file replace, while retaining the encoding, since its not that hard.